# C# WPF Invoking Windows Media Player

Tags: c#, wpf, wmp

I'm currently passing my time by creating a piano app. Each Key is represented of a simple button with a command which fires at click. This leads to executing this Method in ViewModel:

```
    private void PlaySound(object parameter)
    {
        var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.Open(new System.Uri(@SoundBar.GetSoundPathByIdent(int.Parse(parameter.ToString()))));
        mediaPlayer.Play();
    {
```

I think the problem is that the **MediaPlayer** leaves a WeakReference which prevents the GarbageCollector from collecting it. Leading to overloading your RAM after playing a while.

The solution i found was to call: **mediaPlayer.Close();**
But this should only happen after the sound has finished playing, otherwise it will be cut.

Is there a way to check if the played sound has finished playing?

I have already spent some time doing research and testing but i couldn't come up with a working solution.

Comment: [`WeakReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.110).aspx) does **not** prevent the garbage collector from collecting the reference.  That's the entire point of a `WeakReference`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.position(v=vs.110).aspx) and [NaturalDuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.naturalduration(v=vs.110).aspx) properties give you details about where in the stream you're at (ie. `Position / NaturalDuration` gives you a value between 0.0 and 1.0 that represents the playback position as a percentage)

But you may want to build an "orchestrator" for your media playback. Assuming that you don't want to play all sounds at the same time, an orchestrator could be responsible for managing the lifetime of your media players, and determining where in the playback they are.

In your application you could create a single instance of the orchestrator on start up. The orchestrator could create and manage a pool of media players it could reuse when it needs to play a chord. Then your piano app could support a certain number of chords at the same time and have a single poller that determines which media players are free and which are "busy" playing audio.

Comment: In my case, the piano should be able to play pressed sounds at the same time, since i bound the Buttons to certain keys on the keyboard

Comment: Sure, play multiple sounds at the same time, but how many? My point was that you can decide on a reasonable number (say 10, or 16) and then the orchestrator would be responsible for maintaining a pool of mediaPlayer objects which it can use to play the sounds as they come up and when the limit is reached you can decide how to handle that (probably ignore). The orchestrator would know which media players are "free" and which are "busy" by havong two collections